# How can I get the external and internal style (without the inline stytle)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new and trying to write a JS to give a dynamic style. It is the function of **initial value** (for example the `left` property) defined by  external and internal styles.

I can not use `getComputedStyle(element)` to get the  **initial value** within the `EventListener`, as the value changed every time when the JS write the style to the element.

I know that I can get the style value ***out*** of the `EventListener`, so that it will not be affected by the action within the `EventListener`.

But I am still worrying that will the value get from outside of the `EventListener` be lost from the memory? In that case, how can I re-catch the right **initial value**?

PS: I know there is a heavy way is to build a temporary node, which has the same className attach to document within the `EventListener` to get the style value like:

```js
            var tmpNode = document.createElement(node.tagName);
            tmpNode.className = node.className;           
            node.parentNode.appendChild(tmpNode);
            var defaultStyles = Object.assign({}, getStyles(tmpNode));
            node.parentNode.removeChild(tmpNode);
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Without exact code sample reproducing your problem the only kind of answer you may get is similar broad contemplation about the crux of the matter.

Comment: If you know you can get the initial value but don't want to lose it, store it with `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, a `cookie` etc.. That way you can refer back to that original value later.